# Copying zipped files from one nas location to another and then unzipping files in the target location

Tags: batch-file, automation, scripting

I have couple of zipped files in the shared folder or nas folder location.  I need to copy those zipped files from current nas  location to another.

After it is copied then I have to unzip them there in the target nas drive. I tried to use the below batch script code to run but it’s not working. Could you please help me out?

```
@echo off
For F “delims=“ %%I IN  (‘//Nas folder location /b  /s /a-d *.zip‘) 
Do (
 “C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zFM.exe” x -y -o”%%~nI” “%%I”
)
pause
```

Comment: If your batch file is really using those invalid smart, _(curly)_, single , **`‘`**, and double quotes, **`“`** / **`”`**, you need to change them to dumb, _(straight)_, single, **`'`** and double quotes **`"`** instead. Also ```Do (``` must be on the same line as the preceding closing parenthesis, **`)`**

Comment: Can you describe for us where are you having troubles? I am unaware if it's working or not, but it seems that you're just unzipping those files and not copying them.

Comment: Also you should use `7z.exe` instead of 7zFM.exe. The `FM` means it is opening the full file manager. Essentially the application you would use if you launched 7zip from the start menu.  `7z.exe` is the application you should use for scripting.

Comment: Try to read the ZIPs from one NAS and directly extract to the other. Otherwise: you read from one NAS, then write to the other. Then you read from the other, extract and write to the other again. This is double the traffic, unless you need the zipped files on the other NAS, too.

Comment: @echo off
SET SourceDir=\\nasgw013pn\hedis_prod\Cns_Pro_Migration_to_QSI_XL\CPQ_Transform_PRD_files\SRC
SET targetDir=\\nas00872pn\groups\HEDIS\Cns_Pro_Migration_to_QSI_XL\ETL_\TGT
xcopy %sourceDir%\ %targetDir%
"C:\Program Files\7-zip.exe" a "\\nasgw013pn\hedis_prod\Cns_Pro_Migration_to_QSI_XL\CPQ_Transform_PRD_files\SRC\*.zip" -o"\\nas00872pn\groups\HEDIS\Cns_Pro_Migration_to_QSI_XL\ETL_\TGT"
pause

Comment: The below code was used. It copied the files from the source nas drive to the target nas drive successfully. But  gave an error while unzipping which is : cannot open the file as archive. System error: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.